# "Has" vs. "have"

Tags: word-usage, tense, verbs

Can anyone tell me where we have to use "has" and where we have to use "have"?
I am confused. 
Can anyone explain me in a simple way?

Answer (score 7):

As you may know, *have* and *has* are both present forms of the verb *to have* and are employed with the verb *have* alone (for a present simple), with *have/has* (used as an auxiliary verb) and the past participle of another verb (for a present perfect) or with *have/has* (used as an auxiliary verb), the past participle of *be* and the past participle of another verb (for a present perfect continuous).

- ***Has*** is used with a third singular person ("he", "she", "it", or a noun) *i.e.* when the subject is singular but it's neither the person who's writing/speaking ("I") or the person who's reading/listening ("you"):

  > • *He* **has** just asked a question.
- ***Have*** is used in any other case:

  > • Can anyone tell me when *we* **have** to use "have", *etc.*
  >
  > • *I* **have** just copied a sentence from your question.
  >
  > • **Have** *you* noticed it?

[Here](http://conjugator.reverso.net/conjugation-english-verb-have.html) you will find the complete conjugation of the verb.

Comment: It is not broadly used, but third party singular agreement applies to *to-infinitive* and *gerund (or gerund-participle)* when they are used as a subject.

Answer (score 2):

The words 'has' and 'have' are used as a main verb and auxiliary verb in the present tense.

In either case, *has* is used for the third person singular:  he, she, it.

As for *have*, it's used for the third person plural and the first and second persons, singular and plural.

Examples as a main verb:

> He/she **has** a big house.
>
> Mr Smith **has** no car.
>
> It **has** five rooms
>
> They/I/We/You **have** a big house.

Examples as an auxiliary to make sentences in the present perfect:

> He **has** completed his homework.
>
> She **has** had her breakfast.
>
> I **have** completed my homework.
>
> They **have** eaten their food.